# i want to know the runtime changes in dropdown menu item of flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using the drop down search button from pub dev and i am using Text editor controller to get the item search via search box and calling a function via text controller add listener() and I am getting a list of string and assign it to the item parameter of the dropdown but I am not getting the updated result in runtime if I want to see the result I have to close the dropdown and again open it .

You can see my all code here:- https://anotepad.com/notes/hp3xi63p